# The Android App Bundle was signed with the wrong key. Select the correct key and try again

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, google-play-console

`created a new key (android/app/upload-keystore.jks) and what should I do to change it in Google Play Console?

because I lost the new key (accidentally deleted it) there are no copies........

terminal:

> ```
> flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons
> ```

play console where you need to download appbudne (new release):
The Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Select the correct key and try again. The App Bundle must be signed with a digital fingerprint certificate
SHA1: 2B:54:9F:A5......
. However, the downloaded App Bundle uses a digital fingerprint certificate
SHA1: 9B:54:85:D9.....

> ```
> keytool -list -v -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload
> ```
>
> SHA1: 9B:54:85:D9.....

play console where you need to download appbudne:
The Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Select the correct key and try again. The App Bundle must be signed with a digital fingerprint certificate
SHA1: 2B:54:9F:A5......
. However, the downloaded App Bundle uses a digital fingerprint certificate
SHA1: 9B:54:85:D9.....

code:

> `!    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()def keystorePropertiesFile =   rootProject.file('key.properties')if (key .../android/key.properties(here is the data for the key upload-keystore.jks):storePropertiesFile.exists()) {keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))} !`

```
   android {signingConfigs {release {keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']keyPassword                                         keystoreProperties['keyPassword']storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ?   file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : nullstorePassword   keystoreProperties['storePassword']}}
```

```
   buildTypes {release {signingConfig signingConfigs.release}}
```

```
    storePassword=<password-from-previous-step>
    keyPassword=<password-from-previous-step>
    keyAlias=uploadstoreFile=<keystore-file-location>`
```

.../android/key.properties(here is the data for the key upload-keystore.jks)

Comment: I created the Smart.School application, but it was rejected. Lost my key when changing as recommended after being rejected and couldn't find any backups. When trying to upload a new version to the Play Console, I encountered a signature error: “The package was signed with the wrong key.” I tried to update the key, but strange errors arose during the rebuild. I created a new application in the Play Console, but encountered other errors (bundle id of another application or a related one) again, unfortunately, while trying to solve the problem, I lost the key and copies.

Comment: Now I have created a new key, signed the application with it and made backup copies (I’m sure I won’t lose it!) It is possible to change the application signature and also update the key. However, at the moment I'm not sure what action I should take in this situation

Comment: Now I wrote / contacted support (General Play Console issues):
 
https://dev.to/ptkdev/android-reset-password-keystore-file-1o9k  and 

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs

Answer (score 0):

request for a key change in the app integrity section

Comment: I created the Smart.School application, but it was rejected. Lost my key when changing as recommended after being rejected and couldn't find any backups. When trying to upload a new version to the Play Console, I encountered a signature error: “The package was signed with the wrong key.” I tried to update the key, but strange errors arose during the rebuild. I created a new application in the Play Console, but encountered other errors (bundle id of another application or a related one) again, unfortunately, while trying to solve the problem, I lost the key and copies.

Comment: Now I have created a new key, signed the application with it and made backup copies (I’m sure I won’t lose it!) It is possible to change the application signature and also update the key. However, at the moment I'm not sure what action I should take in this situation